# Shortcode not working in custom post types

Tags: shortcode

I have created a shortcode and placed it in my functions.php and registered it with:

```
add_shortcode('featured-attribution', 'gteh_author_shortcode');
```

It works fine on posts and pages.

I created a custom post type, and when I use the shortcode in the content, it just displays the shortcode rather than the function.  I am using `the_content()` to display the content so not sure why it is not working.  In fact, the custom post type is just using `single.php` so not sure why it works on single posts, but not single custom post type pages...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Add `<?php echo has_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode' ) ?>` into your `single.php` file and tell us what will be printed.

Comment: just the number 11 is printed.

Comment: show your `single.php` file.